# localStorage values always Null with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use one function to submit values to `localStorage`, and another function to retrieve them and put them into their respective input fields on the webpage.

My problem is twofold. The `retrieve()` function does not appear to do do anything; not even `Null` is put into the input fields. Secondly, well, I want the `onSubmit()` funciton to actually store the input values.

These are the two functions. I declare `elements` and `s_elements` as you can see, and I attempt to retrieve them. But nothing happens!

```
function retrieve() {
    if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var s_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].getAttribute("type") != "submit" && elements[i].getAttribute("type") != "button") {
                e = elements[i];
                e.setAttribute("value", localStorage[e.getAttribute("name")]);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0; i<s_elements.length; i++) {
            s_e = s_elements[i];
            s_e.setAttribute("value", localStorage[s_e.getAttribute("name")]);
        }
    }
}

function onSubmit() {
    var elements = document.forms["forsendur"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    var s_elements = document.forms["forsendur"].getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].getAttribute("type") != "submit") {
                    e = elements[i];
                    localStorage[e.getAttribute("name")] = e.getAttribute("value");
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i<s_elements.length; i++) {
                s_e = elements[i];
                localStorage[s_e.getAttribute("name")] = s_e.getAttribute("value");
    }
}
```

This is the form with the input values:

```
<form name="forsendur">
    < ... bunch of input and select fields >
    <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Calculate" onClick="onSubmit();"/>

</form>
```

This is the sole button that calls `retrieve()`:

```
<input type="button" class="button2" value="Last session" onClick="retrieve();">
```

EDIT *_* The retrieve() function now works. I fixed a lot of typos. Now only one problem remains.

Comment: Can we see the html for inputs as well? or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Javascript doesn't have block scope. You're reusing the `i` variable in your inner loop. Also, adding some variables so you don't have to keep typing out the long property accesses like `elements[i].getAttribute("name")` would help a lot with readability.

Comment: Indentation error upon copy pasting, sorry. I'll edit the code for readability.

Comment: @Gudmundur "The retrieve() function now works ... Now only one problem remains" - if retrieve is working, then obviously storage is also working. What's the remaining problem then..?

Comment: Storage is still storing values of "Null". I want them to store the input values of the fields. JSFiddle is coming up

Comment: JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vnt62/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vnt62/1/ This one is better, added the JS

Comment: @Gudmundur You're not closing the `onSubmit` function, is it a typo or the real thing?

Comment: Typo, sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: btw even after fixing it, i don't see the `retrieve` function is working in it as you said earlier..!

Comment: Maybe because the jsfiddle version doesn't store anything at all it seems? It works on my end and I copy pasted the code exactly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is that you're trying to use *HTML attributes* instead of *DOM properties* to get your input values.

An *HTML Attribute* is something like this:

`<a href="http://example.com"></a>`

A *DOM Property* can be accessed like this:

`document.querySelector('a').href = 'http://example.com'`

*HTML attributes* are read by your browser as it parses the html text of your site. The browser creates a *DOM Object* representing your html element, and then sets the *attributes* in a way similar to this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com')
```

There are often equivalent *DOM properties* to *HTML attributes* - like the `.href` property I described above.

The difference between these two things(besides the way you access them), is that most events after your HTML page is loaded modify *DOM properties*, not *HTML attributes* - e.g. typing in an `input` will change the `.value` property on the appropriate *DOM Object*, but it won't modify the *HTML attribute*:

`<input type="text" value="hello"/>` - The *HTML attribute* `value` will remain `"hello"`, unless you explicitly set it. Meanwhile, as you type in the input, the *DOM property* `.value` will reflect the text in the input.

To give a specific example in your code, you'd want to change the line
`localStorage[e.getAttribute("name")] = e.getAttribute("value");` <-- using the *HTML attribute* `value`

to

`localStorage[e.getAttribute("name")] = e.value;` <-- using the *DOM property* `.value`